# In which circumstances are suitable for Web Application or Web Site in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, web-applications, web, cassini, asp.net-development-serv

I have one project which has **APP_CODE** folder and runs with **Windows Authentication**.

1) I created **Web Site** and added the files of project but I couldn't run with **windows authentication**

2) Then I created **web application** project and check "Use Visual Studio Development Server". But now, I couldn't get access to the classes which are in App_Code folder.

There is no choice to select **Visual Studio Development Server** when I use **Web Site** project!

Questions:

1. Why can't I add APP_CODE folder to the Web Application ?
2. Why can't I run my Web Application on Visual Studio Development Server?
3. In which circumstances I should choose Web Site or Web Application options ?

**PS:** I want to put pictures of Web Application and Web Site:

**Web Application:**
[image: New Web Application]
[image: Web Application Properties]
[image: ASP_NET Folders for Web Application]

**Web Site:**
[image: New Web Site]
[image: Web Site Properties]
[image: Web Site AS_:NET Folders]